# Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I recently had to upgrade to aws-java-sdk 1.11.108. I have a java program that downloads s3 objects (8 to 10 GB in size) to EC2 box and process it as a stream. This program has had been working for over 2 years w/o any problems, but after updating to the latest version of aws-java-sdk my file-download aborts midway with the following WARN message in the logs (no exception)

`WARN:com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.`

```
S3Object s3Obj = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, s3FileName));
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new  GZIPInputStream(s3Obj.getObjectContent());
```

I will appreciate if somebody can tell why the stream is aborting silently w/o throwing any exception, and what is the best way to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue too when unzipping a file directly into S3.

Comment: do you still have one more place in the club? I am having the same issue with S3.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have no solution so far.

Comment: Same issue here to. Occurs sporadically with Protobuf serialized files.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to `close()` the input stream only once.

Comment: It looks like S3ObjectInputStreams somehow automatically close themselves at EOF???? So doing an explicit close() after the EOF causes this error message.

Answer (score 0):

> ZIP archives have a (redundant) central directory structure at the
>   end, so you can list the contents of the archive without scanning
>   through the whole thing. Java's `ZipInputStream` never actually consumes
>   this from the underlying stream; getNextEntry() returns null as soon
>   as it finds the start of the central directory.
>   You might try adding while (in.read() >= 0); in your overridden close
>   method to read through to the end of the underlying stream?

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1111